# Is there a word to describe the organisation of cells?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology

For example whether an organism is unicellular or multicellular would be its **_**.

There is a word '[cellularity](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/cellularity)', though I don't think that is quite the word I am looking for.

Comment: If you needed a term for that property, in a context where the audience was familiar with both concepts, _cellularity_ would work. But it's not a crucial characteristic; unicels are not monophyletic, except in the possible sense that all life is monophyletic.

Comment: Isn't it cluster?

Comment: classification?

Comment: Cellular arity?  Google gives me no hits, which is why this isn't an answer, but I like it as a phrase anyway.

Comment: The chapter in my high school science textbook was titled *Cell Structure.*

Comment: As this is a technical term, I'd suggest asking at a more biologically oriented site (where it will be more likely that someone will know).

Comment: I think we used "complexity" when I was in school, but I can't remember for sure.

Answer (score 1):

As a sometime cell biologist, I offer that whether an organism is unicellular or multi-cellular is dependent upon its *structure.* I apologize if this feels overly simple, and there are other words that would suffice; however, it is certainly accurate to state that:

- a single-celled organism is and has but one cell, in and around which all the activities of a living thing occur: metabolism, respiration and reproduction being the generally accepted definitions of life
- a multi-cellular organism (that is not a colony of single-celled creatures but, rather, one living entity) has a *body* (structure) consisting of more than one cell, and these cells -- as a whole -- define the organism... and are all (generally) required for all life functions of the organism to take place.

Respectfully, Dr. Jonas Moses

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that it would be something as simple as that

Answer (score 1):

"Cell morphology" describes how it literally looks.